# Assign class to LI based on its index value

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list of LIs and a jQuery variable - I would like to add a class to all the LIs of the jQuery variable and lower.

So...

```
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

And jQuery variable = 2, and the class I want to add is called "complete"

So, I want my list to them become:

```
<ul>
<li class="complete">One</li>
<li class="complete">Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Considere to accept the answer and/or upvote if it's ok for you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try : [slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
var number = 2;
$("li").slice(0,number).attr('class', 'complete');
```

Check the demo : https://jsfiddle.net/d36a5x2h/

Comment: Thanks - yeh seems to work here in your fiddle.. not on my actual site though... i guess my jquery var for the value is a string not integer... need to convert that and should all work ;)

Comment: You can use parseInt() ;)